# Random Emergence

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, aristotle, philosophy-of-physics, ancient-philosophy

In *De Caelo* 300b, Aristotle introduces the idea of the random emergence of the natural:

"it is possible that with this disorderly motion some of the elements might have unified in those combinations which constitute natural bodies"

and then he dismisses the idea.  But notice that this possibility is the defeater of any theory of everything.  Say you had the single mathematical framework and non-arbitrary physical constants that explained everything.  It would still suffer two weaknesses.  First, there could be unseen further facts that are anomalous to the theory.  Second, the mathematical framework and physical constants could be a pattern in an enormous transient of a random sequence.  Then, all physics is just pareidolia or apophenia, even though it is manifestly empirically supported.  Is this skepticism?

Comment: Dictionary.com has a definition for 'pareidolia', but none for 'apophenia'. What is apophenia?

Comment: From Wikipedia, "Apophenia has come to imply a universal human tendency to seek patterns in random information, such as gambling."

Comment: Are you 100% sure he *dismisses* the idea? Aristotle often juxtaposes several arguments for and against a claim  - even several competing hypotheses! - before  putting forward a nuanced alternative. —— While there is a strong reason in Aristotelean physics that  *peri physei* ≠ *peri tychei* and so "natural bodies"  are definitionally not the immediate outcome of random processes, I can't be sure that is relevant to *De Caelo* 300b unless you are certain Aristotle isn't hedging.

Comment: In 301a, he says "no natural event occurs haphazard."  I don't think he is hedging in 300b, I think he is criticizing _Timaeus_ 30a.  For Aristotle, random emergence would be an inconsistent consequence of Plato's pre-cosmos.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. One should keep in mind that physics is thoroughly positivistic but positivism is not a purely logical philosophy. It should be seen a transposition of legal proceedings: evidence is presented and pleas are made, that is facts and theories are used to issue  a judgement which is at best 'beyond reasonable doubt' in the light of what is known. 'Everything might be a coincdence' or 'there might be unknown facts' are hypotheses which would not be considered as arguments. 
Earlier, physicists acted as judges - pondered evidence, read theories and made judgements that were considered to be true; today they act as lawyers who are interested in just winning a case. The key point in legal dealings is who bears the burden of proof. Obviously with the  turn from verifiability to fasifiability a major shifting has occurred.

Comment: I'm not following you.  I also don't understand why "everything might be a coincidence" is not an argument; physicists take care to reduce the chance that observations are coincidences to exceedingly small values.  "There might be unknown facts" is the case where the best model doesn't seem to be quite accurate.